# SOAPUI - Extracting data using jsonpath when element has space

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

I'm attempting to use jsonpath in SOAPUI to facilitate my testing.

I would like to transfer values using property transfer in SOAPUI from a response to a request, however the element has a space.

Below is a extract from the JSON response:

```
"Email address": "EwanWalker@dayrep.com",
                 "NameonCardLine2": null,
```

The expression I would use is as follows:

$.custCriteria.Email address

However this fails.

Comment: Have you tried `$.custCriteria.'Email address'`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and the following:$.custCriteria.['Email address'] or $.custCriteria.[Email address] and $.custCriteria.["Email address"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Answer - $.custCriteria.['Email address'] and using a different online jsonpath validator - http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ instead of http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/